# Sharing props/state between two components in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

So I have a global nav bar component that sits at the home screen and app screen and a music playing component. On click of one of the items in the nav bar I want to mute something on the music component.

Currently, to mute the music etc I'm using state.

So the way I've got this setup is to pass through an object as props and set that as state like so:

```
const obj = {
  playing: false,
  toggleButtonText: 'Play',
  muteActive: false,
};
```

And I pass this as props into my components:

```
<Router>
  <div>
    <Nav stateVal={obj} />
    <Route exact path="/" render={() => <Start />} />
    <Route path="/app" render={() => <App stateVal={obj} />} />
    <Modal />
  </div>
</Router>
```

Then in each of my components, I do:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = this.props.stateVal;
}
```

So the props are set as the state of the component.

My problem is that I want one component to update the `props` and the update the `state` of the other component but I have no idea how I'm going to do that?

Could anyone give me a bit of help or pointers?

Comment: I don't understand why you need to set the props to state as you are doing? Props can change, and you don't seem to be dealing with that. However, if I understand the design pattern properly, this is a case for Redux or a similar tool as you are really attempting to manage global state from a leaf node component.

Comment: I read about redux @ChidG but my app is so small that I thought it was overkill, like it's literally just a home screen, music playing component and a nav bar

Comment: Sure, perhaps it is overkill for your app. Otherwise, you'll need to set the props on a parent component that wraps both the child components that need to be connected and have the props pass down to them as explained in Martin's answer.

Comment: @ChidG ahh cheers! Yeah, at the moment they're not wrapped in a single component so that's what I'm missing I think.

Answer (score 1):

Assigning props to state in constructor is an anti-pattern because if the props change later on then the state isn't going to change.

Have the component update the props of the parent and then pass the props down the other child.

If you can't do this for some reason then you should look into Redux, Flux or MobX to handle the state.

Example

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
    setMusicActive = (muteActive) => {
        this.setState({ muteActive });
    }
    <ChildOne muteActive={this.state.muteActive} setMusicActive={this.setMuteActive} />
    <ChildTwo muteActive={this.state.muteActive} setMusicActive={this.setMuteActive} />
}

class ChildOne extends React.Component {
    someOtherFunction = () => {
        this.props.setMuteActive(!this.props.muteActive);
    }
}
```

Updates the value in one place and you can use it in the children.

Comment: I'm fairly new to react still learning. How would I go about getting the component to update the props of the parent? That's the bit I'm struggling with

Comment: @PourMeSomeCode added example. Redux is probably overkill if you only have simple setup like the example. If you are having to pass functions multiple grandchildren down to do this then it may be time for Redux